# How to Hide a Tablix based on another Tablix's Visibility setting in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

How do we go about hiding a tablix based on another tablix's visibility setting? I have two tablixes on a report that are linked to another report. I'd like them to alternate (hide one when the other show).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an expression that determines whether Tablix1 is displayed or not, surely the solution to this is to set the Tablix2 visibility to be the opposite. e.g.

Tablix1 - `Hidden` property

```
=iif(condition, false, true)
```

Tablix2 - `Hidden` property

```
=iif(condition, true false)
```

I admit this does mean doubling up the code, but I'm not aware of a way for a report element to reference the properties of the other items on the report other than `.Value`.